# Filter correlation matrix ands its p-value matrix with R

Tags: r

I have two matrix, one with correlation stats and another with p-values, they have 942 x 942 dimensions and I need to filter first the significative p-values (< 0.005) and then extract the significative correlations (> 0.60).

I alredy filter de p- values with the next code:

```
pvalues <- as.matrix (pvalues)
pvalues[pvalues > 0.05] <- NA
```

But now, I need to extract the stats and the same objects from the other matrix, and it must haver more than 0.60. Is it any way to do this?

Any suggestion will be appreciate, thanks very much.

Comment: You are not clear about what results you want. You matrix has 887,364 entries. 942 are correlations between the same variable and are all +1.0 along the diagonal of the matrix. Then there are 443,211 correlations above the diagonal and 443,211 correlations below the diagonal. These two sets are identical. Do you want all of the pairs of identical correlations or just the top or bottom diagonal? Do you want the values or the indices (e.g. row 3, column 5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I melted both df

```
pvalues.melt <- melt(pvalues)
stats.corr.melt <- melt(stats.corr)
```

Then, I save de stats as a vector and add that column to the p-value data frame

```
stats <- as.vector(stats.corr.melt$value)
pvalues.stats <- cbind(pvalues.melt, stats)
```

Then, I filtered both. First, the p-values (<0.05).

```
pvalues.filter <- filter(pvalues.stats, value < 0.05)
```

And, next the stats (< -0.06 or > 0.06)

```
stats.filter <- filter(pvalues.filter, stats < -0.6 | stats > 0.6)
```

All that remains is to transform it back into a matrix.